# Why my code doesn't execute and how can I execute it?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.8

It got executed once but I add some features and now it doesn't work anymore...
I'm a beginner at python and this is my first project. I'd like to create a game (which works perfectly in the console) but I have some troubles to put it with  tkinter
If someone could take a look at this, it would be nice, thanks
Here's my code, I might have mistyped something or I don't know but I'm stucked with this and I can't find the mistake.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Canvas, Button, Frame, Toplevel, Entry
from random import randrange
num = randrange(0, 50)
money = 100
   
root = Tk()

root.geometry("750x750")
root["bg"]="beige"

label = Label(root, text="Welcome to the Casino")
label.place(width=180, x=300, y=300)

def csn(x, y, z, i):
    if y < 50 and y >= 0 and z <= i :
        if y == x:
            i += z * 3
            return "Well guess. You have %d"  %(i)
        elif (x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0) or ( x % 2 != 0 and y % 2 != 0):
            i += z * 0.5
            return "Not so ba. You have %d" %(i)
        else:
            i -= z
            return "Oops, Try again, you loose %d. You now have %d" %(z, i)
    else:
         return "Try again..."


def submit(master):
    label1 = Label(master, text="try again...")
    label1.place(width=180, x=300, y=300)

def casino():
    top = Toplevel()
    top['bg']= 'blue'
    top.geometry = ('700x700')
    root.withdraw
    while money > 0:
        try:
            number_label = Label(top, text="Chose a nombre : ")
            number_label.place(width=180, x=100, y=300)
            nentry= Entry(top)
            nentry.place(width=180, x=200, y=300)
            number = int(nentry.get())
    
            
            mise_label = Label(top, text="Entre the price you want to mise : ")
            mise_label.place(width=180, x=100, y=400)
            mise_entry = Entry(top)
            mise_entry.place(width=180, x=200, y=400)
            mise = float(mise_entry.get())
            
        
        
        except ValueError:
            btn3 = Button(top, text="submit", command=lambda : submit(top))
            btn3.place(width=180, x=300, y=300)

        btn = Button(top, text="submit", command= lambda : csn(num, number, mise, money))
        btn.place(width=180, x=300, y=500)
    else:
        label2= Label(top, text="you lose")
        label2.place(width=180, x=300, y=500)
        btn1 = Button(top, text="Quit", command=top.quit)
        btn1.place(width=180, x=300, y=400)
        btn2 = Button(top, text="try again", command=casino)
        btn2.place(width=180, x=200, y=400)

    enter code here

button = Button(root, text="play!", relief='groove', command=casino)
button.place(width=180, x=300, y=400)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What features did you try to add? What is the desired behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: first, replace your while loop with the if statement. Because the whileloop is constantly calling the toplevel. Then please ,clean your code up to the point you do not know how to solve it, that we dont need to write the whole code.

Comment: @michalwa I just add some functions to make my button run. Before this when i ran the code, I had a window and when I clik the button "play" , it opens a new window but there's nothing in this so I tried to make some changes and now when i clik the play button, I get nothing, my code run but my second window doesn't appear.

Comment: After @Thingamabobs' comment. You're having typo error `top.geometry = ('700x700')`  should be `top.geometry('700x700')` .  Noticed in `csn` function, `y`  and `z` are none. Merely `x` and `i` are returned. You're messed up with parameter `csn(x, y, z, i)` = `lambda : csn(num, number, mise`, money in keyword command.We don't know if `y` is represented by `money`, nor `num`, nor `index`, nor `random`.